# Personal pronoun - Using 'it' when introducing a person

Tags: pronouns, syntactic-analysis, agreement, dummy-it, pronominal-agreement

On the NPR radio program Wait Wait Don't Tell Me (http://www.npr.org/programs/wait-wait-dont-tell-me/) Peter Sagal introduces the week's panelists using 'it's,' as in "She'll be performing Friday at the Comedy Club, *it's* Paula Poundstone." I'm not sure it is grammatically incorrect, but it doesn't seem appropriate to refer to a person as "it."  Wouldn't it be better to say "she is" in this case? Or better yet, use another phrase, such as "we welcome..." or "say hello to..?"

I have heard similar usage on other radio and television programming as well when the gender is known to the speaker, where "it is" replaces "she/he is/has."  Is this now acceptable usage?

Comment: In your context, the expression *"it's Paula Poundstone"* can be considered to be a truncated *it*-cleft. -- This usage is acceptable and has been for a long time. It is part of today's standard English.

Comment: Totally. This is not 'referential it' (as contrasted with 'he' and 'she') but 'delexical it' as in 'It's raining / It's eleven o'clock / It's John on the phone). "It's" in 'It's Tommy Cooper!" has virtually the same meaning as "Look who it is!" in "Look who it is – Tommy Cooper!"  French has two different usages (ce as opposed to il/elle). One can even say 'It's us' which apparently contravenes agreement-for-number rules as well as agreement-of-gender-if-any rules.

Comment: This flavor of *it* is never intended to agree with what comes after.  “It’s your parents.  It’s me.  It’s you.”

Comment: As King Arthur sings in Camelot, *C'est moi, c'est moi, T'is I.*

Comment: Paula Poundstone has no gender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***It's Paula Poundstone*** seems to me to simply be the answer to an
(unspoken but presupposed) question

> **Q:** *Who is it?*
>    **A:** *It's Paula.*

A question like *Who is this person?* is taken as a given in any formal introduction.
And this is the introduction of a number of speakers on stage before a performance.

There are special conventions for this context, as there are for telephone conversation,

> (e.g, consider the strangeness of *"Hello, this is Bill. Is this Mary?*", outside a phone conversation)

and one of the conventions is that the introducer often says, of each introducee,

- ***It's*** (but almost never ***It is***) ***`<Insert Name>`!***

frequently adding phrases like *And now; Appearing at the Palace nightly; The one, the only,* etc.

Answer (score 3):

I've always understood this as indicating the state/situation of that person being present.

"She's Paula Pountstone" means "That person(she) is Paula Poundstone."

"It's Paula Poundstone." means "The situation(it) is that Paula Poundstone is here."

Answer (score 3):

> - *"She'll be performing Friday at the Comedy Club,* ***it's Paula Poundstone."***

In your context, the expression "it's Paula Poundstone" can be considered to be a truncated *it*-cleft. This usage is acceptable and has been for a long time. It is part of today's standard English.

The *it*-cleft's relative clause has been omitted, because its info is redundant and can be recovered from the context. The subject of the main clause of the *it*-cleft is the dummy pronoun "it". The dummy pronoun does not refer to anything or anybody: that is, it has no antecedent or referent.

The following is what your example basically means, with the omitted relative clause stuck back in using italics:

- "She'll be performing Friday at the Comedy Club, **it's Paula Poundstone** *who will be performing Friday at the Comedy Club*."

There are other threads here that are similar to yours. If you want more info or links to them, go ahead and ask.